# Statistical Analysis with repeated measures categorical data

Tags: categorical-data, repeated-measures, biostatistics, jmp

For my Master thesis I looked at behavioral responses of fish by quantifying their position as a reaction to a certain treatment.

I have 20 Fish that I measured on 7 consecutive days. Every day, each individual got to see all 4 Treatments once.

The variable I measured is categorical (Zone 1, Zone 2, Zone 3).
Since I measured each fish with each treatment 7 times, i have repeated measures. But with categorical data... How do I do this? What Test can I use? Usually I would take the mean "something" (lets say the mean distance) per Fish and get one independent data point per fish, but categorical data confuses me... I can't take the mean "Zone".

My Supervisor wants me to use JMP for data analysis (eventhough I'd prefer SPSS).

If any of you knows a test I can use, I'd appreciate your help! 
I see this has been a familar poblem in the past (judging from what I find on the internet so far).

Thanks!

Comment: Can you think of the zones as ordered (ie, one end of the tank, the middle, the other end)?

Comment: In a way, yes (one zone is closer to the treatment, another one is further away)